# Why does my function work in g++, but not in LeetCode?

Tags: c++, g++

I'm trying to submit code for this question, https://leetcode.com/problems/zigzag-conversion/

I'm using g++ to compile on my system. It works and outputs all the example solutions correctly on my end. However, it keeps giving me an error when I put the code into the submission area.

Here's a look at my code...

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Solution {
public:
    string convert(string s, int numRows) 
    {
        int size = s.size();
        int i, j;
        
        string *zigZag = new string[numRows];
        char* retStr = new char[size];
        
        int count = 0;
        bool moreString = true;
        int col = 0;

        while(moreString)
        {
            for(i = 0; i< numRows && count < size; i++)
            {
                zigZag[i][col] = s[count];
                count++;
            }

            col++;

            for(i = numRows - 2; i > 0 && count < size; i--)
            {
                zigZag[i][col] = s[count];
                count++;
                col++;
            }

            if(count >= size)
                moreString = false;
        }

        count = 0;
        for(i = 0; i < numRows; i++)
        {
            for(j = 0; j < col; j++)
            {
                if(zigZag[i][j] !=  '\0')
                {
                    retStr[count] = zigZag[i][j];
                    count++;
                } 
            }
        }

        return retStr;

    }
};
```

This is the error it keeps spitting out at me...

```
=================================================================
==31==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: heap-buffer-overflow on address 0x60200000001e at pc 0x0000003441f4 bp 0x7ffdf5b48350 sp 0x7ffdf5b48348
WRITE of size 1 at 0x60200000001e thread T0
    #3 0x7f93f12dd0b2  (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x270b2)
0x60200000001e is located 0 bytes to the right of 14-byte region [0x602000000010,0x60200000001e)
allocated by thread T0 here:
    #4 0x7f93f12dd0b2  (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x270b2)
Shadow bytes around the buggy address:
  0x0c047fff7fb0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x0c047fff7fc0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x0c047fff7fd0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x0c047fff7fe0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x0c047fff7ff0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
=>0x0c047fff8000: fa fa 00[06]fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x0c047fff8010: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x0c047fff8020: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x0c047fff8030: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x0c047fff8040: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x0c047fff8050: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
Shadow byte legend (one shadow byte represents 8 application bytes):
  Addressable:           00
  Partially addressable: 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 
  Heap left redzone:       fa
  Freed heap region:       fd
  Stack left redzone:      f1
  Stack mid redzone:       f2
  Stack right redzone:     f3
  Stack after return:      f5
  Stack use after scope:   f8
  Global redzone:          f9
  Global init order:       f6
  Poisoned by user:        f7
  Container overflow:      fc
  Array cookie:            ac
  Intra object redzone:    bb
  ASan internal:           fe
  Left alloca redzone:     ca
  Right alloca redzone:    cb
  Shadow gap:              cc
==31==ABORTING
```

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you remember that C-style string arrays needs to be ***null-terminated***?

Comment: Compile it with address sanitizer then, you should see the same error.

Comment: Why do you even use dynamic allocation and `char` arrays? What's wrong with `std::vector` and `std::string`? Are you using that site to learn C++ and programming? Because that's not the purpose of such sites, their purpose is to act as simple brain-teasers and puzzles, nothing more. They're definitely not any kind of learning or teaching resource, despite what some might say or claim. All they might teach are bad habits and bad (and sometimes even invalid) code.

Comment: `string *zigZag = new string[numRows];` Change to --> `std::vector<std::string> zigZag(numRows);`.  And then: `char* retStr = new char[size];` Change to --> `std::string retStr; retStr.resize(size);`

Comment: `zigZag[i]` is empty when you try to access index `col` => segmentation fault.

Comment: please post the [mcve] you compile and run on your system.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is that Leetcode seems to run your code with the address sanitizer. Gcc has some facilities to spot bugs in code that is syntactically correct and does not trigger compiler errors. The output you see can be generated with gcc and the flag `-fsanitize=address`: https://godbolt.org/z/1jse1snW7

As mentioned in comments the reason is that

```
string *zigZag = new string[numRows];
```

Allocates an array of pointers to `string` and then here:

```
zigZag[i][col] = s[count];
```

you assume that `zigZag[i]` points to an array, but you never allocated that array. As a result `zigZag[i][col]` dereferences an invalid pointer and is undefined behavior.